# DatePicker and TimePicker Android don't show year, month, day, hour and minute

Tags: android, datepicker, android-timepicker

I'm getting some problems with the control DatePicker and TimePicker for a device with this dimensions (400 x 800px) and Android 4.2.2.

Then, I show you the problem in this link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuO2u.jpg

Instead of appear the numbers for the date and time, it appears anything, only white spaces. In other devices with differents screen dimensions and versions works normally.

Thanks!!

This is my code for both

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpFecha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/tpHora"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

And JAVA; in this code I put Date and Time picker controls into a AlertDialog:

```
View tituloView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dtitle, null);
    FrameLayout flTitulo = (FrameLayout) tituloView
            .findViewById(R.id.flTitulo);

    Builder bdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(frmCitaInfo.this)
            .setCustomTitle(tituloView).setView(
                    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dcdatetime, null));

    final AlertDialog dialog = bdialog.create();
    dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    dialog.show();

    final DatePicker dpFecha = (DatePicker) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.dpFecha);
    final TimePicker tpHora = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tpHora);
```

Comment: Post your code (initialisation of pickers)

Comment: Ok!! I edit my question with code

Comment: Is the `minSdkVersion` correctly set to support 4.2.2?

Comment: mmm no, this is: android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: try to init your pickers by some values. example the time picker: Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
tpHora.setCurrentHour(hour);
tpHora.setCurrentMinute(min);

Comment: Thanks @Rami, I hadn't init the date of the calendar, my problem get resolved !!!